# Binding a promise handler function to an object

Tags: javascript, promise

I have some code like:

```
var bar = foo().then(function success(value) {
  // compute something from a value...
}, function failure(reason) {
  // handle an error...
});
```

How do I bind the `failure` function to the `this` object in the context of `bar`. I know I will have to use `myFunc.bind(this)` but what do I substitute in place of `myFunc`?

Comment: What kind of promisses are you talking about? JavaScript promisses is still under discussion for ES6

Comment: Yes, I am talking about JavaScript promises.

Comment: That's hard to believe, the es6 javascript promises are still not implemented. You need to provide more context. http://mozilla.6506.n7.nabble.com/Promise-Future-asynchrony-in-then-td278846.html#a279080

Comment: @fmsf Promises are not really the important part here :)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use `bind` like this:

```
var bar = foo().then(function success(value) {
  // compute something from a value...
}, function failure(reason) {
  // handle an error...
}.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 6):

You currently have an anonymous (although labelled) function for your failure callback:

```
function failure(reason) {
   // handle an error...
}
```

As robertklep says, you can immediately call `.bind` on that anonymous function. However, it might be more readable to use a named function instead, and pass it into `.then()` as a variable:

```
function success(value) {
    // compute something from a value...
}
function failure(reason) {
    // handle an error...
}
var bar = foo().then(success, failure.bind(this));
```

Comment: I think you mean `failure = failure.bind(this)`?

Comment: @robertklep Ah, could be; I'm not really familiar with `.bind()`. If it returns a new object, rather than acting in place, I suppose `foo().then(success, failure.bind(this));` would be quite readable.

Comment: yes it returns a new object :) as for being more readable, that's a matter of debate ;)

Comment: @robertklep It's subjective indeed; but the very fact that this question was needed suggests that many people don't find function literals very easy to conceptualise - they just use an anonymous callback because that's what they're used to doing, and don't realise that they're creating and passing a function object.

Comment: Agreed, and your suggestion works fine if `foo()` is the only function that returns a promise that you want handled. But if there are more functions like that, you end up with multiple `success` and `failure` functions (all with a different name) and code gets messy quickly.

Comment: @robertklep Very true. On the other hand, you might want to use the *same* failure callback with multiple promises (but perhaps bind it to different values for `this`)... Both approaches have their place, and the important thing is to realise they will both work just as well. :)

Answer (score 5):

If you are only interested in the object `this` of the enclosing scope, and you are using ECMA6 or later, you could use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). It would look like:

```
var that = this;
var bar = foo().then(value => {
  // compute something from a value...
  console.log(this === that); // true
  this.propA = value.propA
});
```

You could find more examples in [MSD Using promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

Answer (score 0):

What I found very useful is to bind each `then()`'s [function] handler to the one empty object, so each function could have the access to it. Then the user can set and get the properties in each Promise by `this` keyword. The unit test frameworks works similarly.

```js
    chainPromiseList([getName,getAge],finalDone,rejectHandle);

    function chainPromiseList(promiseList,finalDone,errHandle){
      var userContext = new UserContext();
      if(typeof finalDone==='function') promiseList.push(finalDone);
      if(typeof errHandle==='function') promiseList.push(errHandle);
      return promiseList.reduce((total,curVal,curInd,arr)=>{
        var last = curInd+1===arr.length;
        var method = last&&typeof errHandle==='function' ? 'catch':'then';
        var concatenated = total[method](curVal.bind(userContext));
        return concatenated;
      },Promise.resolve());
        function UserContext(){};
    }
    
    function getName(){
      return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
          console.log('got name!');
          this.name = 'Paul';
          resolve();
        },500);
      });
    }

    function getAge(){
      return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
          console.log('got age!');
          this.age = 26;
          resolve();
        },500);
      });
    }

    function finalDone(){
      console.log(`Hello, I'm ${this.name} and I'm ${this.age}yo.`);
    }

    function rejectHandle(msg){
      console.log('Error: ',msg);
    }
```